# Trying to write a function that can accept an optional parameter and based on it's type, filter and return an icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have two separate alert icon functions written with TypeScript that I'm using in my React app.

One function runs at the header level of a school and displays alerts for the whole organization. The other function runs at the individual school level showing only alerts for that location.

Both functions are almost identical and in the spirit of DRY, I'm trying to write a single function that can be used anywhere in the application either at the top or location level.

The issue I'm running into is that the data elements for each alert function are different types, at the header level the function receives an object with a top level attribute called 'alertType', while the location level function receives an object with a nested attribute called 'summary', and I can't figure out how to write the function to accept either type as a parameter and then based on what gets passed in, produce the appropriate icons.

I tried to write a few separate `if` statements to check if a certain attribute exists on the parameter and perform the rest of the function based on that but TypeScript keeps throwing errors saying `property does not exist on type: LocationAlerts | Summary[] | null`.

I have my original functions for both the top level alerts and the school location alerts with examples on how they're called as well as my current attempt to create a single function for both.

`School top level function`

```
export const showWeatherAlertIcon = (summary: Summary[] | null) => {
  if (!summary) {
    return false;
  }
  const filteredAlerts = summary.filter(a => a.alertType.toUpperCase() === 'WEATHER');
  return filteredAlerts.length > 0 ? true : false;
};

export const showSpecialEventIcon = (summary: Summary[] | null) => {
  if (!summary) {
    return false;
  }
  const filteredAlerts = summary.filter(a => a.alertType.toUpperCase() === 'SPECIALEVENT');
  return filteredAlerts.length > 0 ? true : false;
};

// Example of how the function is called
export const AlertSummary = () => {
  const store = SchoolStore.useStore();
  const alerts = store.get('schoolAlertsTop');
  return (
    <>
      {alerts && alerts.data && (
        <IconSection>
          {showWeatherAlertIcon(alerts.data.alertSummary) && (
            <TooltipHover toolTipContent={'INCLEMENT WEATHER'}>
              <span>
                <WeatherIcon />
              </span>
            </TooltipHover>
          )}
         ...
        </IconSection>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

`Examples of School Location Level function`

```
export const showWeatherAlertIcon = (locationAlerts: LocationAlerts | null) => {
  if (!locationAlerts || !locationAlerts.alertSummary) {
    return false;
  }
  const filteredAlerts = locationAlerts.alertSummary.filter(a => a.alertType.toUpperCase() === 'WEATHER');
  return filteredAlerts.length > 0 ? true : false;
};

export const showSpecialEventIcon = (locationAlerts: LocationAlerts | null) => {
  if (!locationAlerts || !locationAlerts.alertSummary) {
    return false;
  }
  const filteredAlerts = locationAlerts.alertSummary.filter(
    a => a.alertType.toUpperCase() === 'SPECIALEVENT'
  );
  return filteredAlerts.length > 0 ? true : false;
};

// Example of how the function is called
<AlertContainer>
      {!location.alertDetails ||
       !location.alertDetails.alertSummary ||
       location.alertDetails.alertSummary.length === 0 ? (
          <NoAlerts>NO ALERTS</NoAlerts>
           ) : (
           <IconBox title={`ALERTS`}>
              <div className="alert-icon-container">
                {showWeatherAlertIcon(location.alertDetails) && (
                  <TooltipHover toolTipContent={'INCLEMENT WEATHER'}>
                    <span>
                      <WeatherIcon />
                     </span>
                   </TooltipHover>
                 )}
                  ...
           </IconBox>
          )
</AlertContainer>
```

`Example of Single Function for both`

```
export const showWeatherAlertIcon = (alerts: Summary[] | LocationAlerts | null) => {
  if (!alerts) {
    return false;
  }


  if (alerts && alerts.alertSummary) {
    const filteredAlerts = alerts.alertSummary.filter(a => a.alertType.toUpperCase() === 'WEATHER');
    return filteredAlerts.length > 0 ? true : false;
  }

  if(alerts){
    const filteredHeaderAlerts = alerts.filter(a => a.alertType.toUpperCase() === 'WEATHER');
    return filteredHeaderAlerts.length > 0 ? true : false;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing because I assume that alertSummary in your LocationAlerts type is not nullable? If you make it nullable then I think the code you have might work.

A better approach would be to create a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to determine which type "alerts" is e.g.

```
const isLocationAlerts 
 = (alerts: Summary[] | LocationAlerts): alerts is LocationAlerts 
 => (alerts as LocationAlerts).alertSummary !== undefined
```

And then use it like so:

```
export const showWeatherAlertIcon = (alerts: Summary[] | LocationAlerts | null) => {
  if (!alerts) {
    return false;
  }

  // Note: Not sure of your alert type so I've set it to any
  const isWeatherAlert = (alert: any) => alert.alertType.toUpperCase() === 'WEATHER';

  return isLocationAlerts(alerts) ?
    alerts.alertSummary.some(isWeatherAlert) : 
    alerts.some(isWeatherAlert);
};
```